# Asterisk on Date Picker DataCard Does Not Disappear when Date Selected in Power Apps

Tags: powerapps-forms, date, datepicker, required

I am trying to hide the 'Submit' button until all required fields are completed. When I set the following formula on the astrisk for the Date Picker DataCard in Power Apps, the asterisk disappears and I am not able to add the function in this formula:

1. Select each asterisk, and change color to red.
2. For each asterisk, change **Visible** control to: `And(!Parent.Valid, Parent.DisplayMode=DisplayMode.Edit)`
3. Select the button (e.g., Submit button).
4. Change **DisplayMode** control to: `If(FormName.Valid, DisplayMode.Edit, DisplayMode.Disabled)`
5. Change **DisabledColor** control to:
   `ColorFade(ButtonName.Color, -50%)`
6. Change **Tooltip** control to:
   `If(ButtonName.DisplayMode = DisplayMode.Edit, “Submit Form”, “Please complete all fields before submitting.”)`
7. Save Power Apps.
8. Done.

Can you help me understand why the asterisk disappears from the Date Picker DataCard? How can I correct this, so that when the date is selected by the user, the asterisk disappears?

Comment: Asterisk for date picker control is disappearing before selecting the date? Is there any default value set for this control? Is this happening only for date control or other controls as well (text input/drop down)?

Comment: Try this & let me know if it works: https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/DatePicker-empty-value/td-p/38305

Comment: @GaneshSanap. I found that I had asterisks on hidden fields. The formula does work, but I had to notice that I had hidden fields. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check for hidden fields. That was my issue. After adding an 'If' clause to the hidden starcard, it worked.